# Solve $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1-16k^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, fourier-series

I could use some help on calculating this infinite sum: $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1-16k^2}$. Included was that I had to start with a Fourier series for the function $f:\Re \to \Re: x \mapsto \sin(x)$ for $x\in[0, \frac{\pi}{2}[$, so let's start with that.

Let 
\begin{eqnarray*}
g(x) = \frac{a_0}{2} + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_k\cos(4kx) + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}b_k\sin(4kx).
\end{eqnarray*} 
This is the Fourier series for $f$.
With $a_k = \frac{4}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sin(x)\cos(4kx)dx$ and $b_k = \frac{4}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sin(x)\sin(4kx)dx$. Solving this leads to (or at least I found that): $a_k = \frac{4}{(1-16k^2)\pi}$, $b_k = \frac{16k}{(1-16k^2)\pi}$ for $k\geq1$ and $a_0 = \frac{4}{\pi}$. Bringing this to $g(x)$ gives:
\begin{eqnarray*}
g(x) = \frac{2}{\pi} + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{4}{(1-16k^2)\pi}\cos(4kx) + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{16k}{(1-16k^2)\pi}\sin(4kx). 
\end{eqnarray*}
Since $f(x) \approx g(x)$, we can say that $f(0) = g(0)$. We get 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sin(0) = \frac{2}{\pi} + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{4}{(1-16k^2)\pi}\cos(0) + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{16k}{(1-16k^2)\pi}\sin(0),
\end{eqnarray*}
this becomes 
\begin{eqnarray*}
0 = \frac{2}{\pi} + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{4}{(1-16k^2)\pi}.
\end{eqnarray*}
We get 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{-2}{\pi} = \frac{4}{\pi}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1-16k^2}
\end{eqnarray*} so 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1-16k^2} = \frac{-1}{2}.
\end{eqnarray*} We need the sum from k = 0. The term $\frac{1}{1-16k^2}$ for k = 0 gives 1, so we add 1 to both sides. This leads to my solution 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1-16k^2} = \frac{1}{2}.
\end{eqnarray*}

However, when approaching this sum numerically and using Wolfram, I find that the sum should be $\frac{4+\pi}{8}$. Could some help and point out where I went wrong with my approach? Thanks in advance

Comment: Good Job.Looks much better :-) ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason that the approach in the OP is flawed is that the Fourier series for $\sin(x)$ for $x\in [0,\pi/2]$ is discontinuous at the end points.  This is [Gibb's Phenomenon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbs_phenomenon).

In fact, we have

$$\sin(x)= \frac2\pi +\frac4\pi\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\cos(4nx)}{1-16n^2}+\frac{16}{\pi}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n\sin(4nx)}{1-16n^2}$$

for $x\in (0,\pi/2)$ pointwise, but the convergence is $L^2[0,\pi/2]$.  We do not have pointwise convergence at the end points.  This is not surprising given $\sin(0)=0\ne \sin(\pi/2)=1$.

And since $\sin(0)=0$ and $\sin(\pi/2)=1$ we have

$$\frac{1+0}{2}=\frac2\pi +\frac4\pi\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{1-16n^2} \tag 1$$

Solving $(1)$ the series of interest yields

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{1-16n^2} =1+\frac\pi4\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{2}{\pi}\right)=\frac{4+\pi}{8}$$

as expected!

Comment: Good answer, it get's the answer & uses Fourier series as requested.

Comment: Edit ? $sin(\color{red}{4} nx)$ in the first equation ?

Comment: Thanks, this resolved my issue. I'll get myself informed about the Gibb's Phenomenon. Thanks to all who helped me on this!

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit Thank you.  Much appreciative.  And good catch;  I've edited.

Comment: @marcocantarini Thank you Marco.  Much appreciative.

Answer (score 6):

First lets tidy the sum up a little
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1-16k^2}=1-\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{16k^2-1}
\end{eqnarray*}
Now partial fractions gives
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{16k^2-1}= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \left( \frac{1/2}{4k-1}-\frac{1/2}{4k+1} \right)
\end{eqnarray*}
Now use $\frac{1}{i}= \int_0^1 x^{i-1} dx $. We have
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{16k^2-1}= \frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\int_0^1   \left( x^{4k-2}-x^{4k} \right) dx
\end{eqnarray*}
Now interchange the sum & the integral.... & perform the geometric sums
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{16k^2-1}=\frac{1}{2} \int_0^1  \left( \frac{x^2-x^4}{1-x^4} \right) dx = \frac{1}{2}\int_0^1   \left( \frac{x^2}{1-x^2} \right) dx =\frac{1}{2}(1-\frac{\pi}{4}). 
\end{eqnarray*}
Now putting it all back together ... we have $\color{red}{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\pi}{8}}$.

Comment: Thanks for the response! While this certainly is a very nice (using that integral) and valid way to calculate the sum, I'm looking more for a Fourier series based approach and correction of my method. But you're right about tidying up the sums (I don't have much LaTeX experience).

Comment: When I said tidy up ... I mean't make it easier to mathematically manipulate ... When you find some LaTex you like the look of, highlight it, right click, take the first option (show math as), then take the second option (TeX commands) ... it will show you the latex commands ! ... Do it on my answer & borrow the eqnarray stuff ... edit your question ? ... in the meanwhile I will try your question using your fourier series method.

Comment: Yeah I was busy doing that. Thanks again for the help :)

Comment: This doesn't address the question.  Gibb's Phenomenon is the issue.

Comment: This is overkill. Alternatively, a simple rearrangement makes the result obvious:
$$\frac{2}{1-16k^2} = \frac{1}{4k+1} -\frac{1}{4k-1}
= \frac{1}{2(2k+1)-1} - \frac{1}{2(2k) - 1}$$
so we obtain two terms for each of the former series:
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1-16k^2}
= \frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{2n-1}
= \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{2n-1}= \frac{1}{2} + \frac{\pi}{8}$$
where we evaluate the summation as the famous Leibniz formula

Comment: @adfriedman ... You are right. As I read your solution, I realised it is the alternating sum of odd reciprocals ... pi by 4 ! I have certainly taken the long path to get there ?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it is interesting to see that this series can be easily calculated with the residue theorem. Observing that $$S=\sum_{n\geq0}\frac{1}{1-16n^{2}}=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\frac{1}{1-16n^{2}}+\frac{1}{2}$$ and [using](http://www.supermath.info/InfiniteSeriesandtheResidueTheorem.pdf) $$\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}f\left(n\right)=-\sum\left\{ \textrm{Res}\left(\pi\cot\left(\pi z\right)f\left(z\right)\right)\textrm{ at }f\left(z\right)\textrm{'s poles}\right\} $$ and observing that we have poles at $z=\pm\frac{1}{4}$ we get $$S=\color{red}{\frac{\pi}{8}+\frac{1}{2}}$$ as wanted.

Comment: Not an answer to the question, but (+1) becausebecause it's useful to have alternative ways forward, I like to see both purely real and complex analysis results, and this particular tool has widespread use in evaluating series.