# $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{16n^2-1}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

How can I calculate $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{16n^2-1}$$ using the Fourier series?

Comment: It may be helpful to use $\frac1{16n^2-1}=\frac12(\frac1{4n-1}-\frac1{4n+1})$.

Comment: I've already thought about it but I don't know how to use it

Comment: Since it can be written as a sum @Kenta S pointed out, you should be able to evaluate it using the contour integral method. That's what physicists often call Matsubara trick.

Comment: I haven't studied countour integral method

Comment: see https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2216441/991443

Comment: Please don't try to delete your question. I rolled back your changes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

\begin{align}
|\sin(x)|&=\frac2{\pi}-\frac4{\pi}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\cos(2nx)}{4n^2-1}\\\\
\therefore\left|\sin\left(\frac\pi 4\right)\right|&=\frac2{\pi}-\frac4{\pi}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\cos\left(\frac{n\pi} 2\right)}{4n^2-1}\\
&=\frac2{\pi}-\frac4{\pi}\sum_{n=even}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n/2}}{4n^2-1}\\
(n\rightarrow 2m)&=\frac2{\pi}-\frac4{\pi}\sum_{m=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^m}{16m^2-1}\\\\
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{16n^2-1}&=\frac{\frac2{\pi} - \frac{\sqrt2}2 }{\frac4\pi}
\end{align}